# MySQL - Change Entry Category ID?

Tags: categories, mysql

Looking for help doing what I hope is a simple task.

We have approximately 2500 entries that are need to be reclassified (choose new category ID).  I am hoping that a simple MySQL script can identify all the records with a certain category id, and then change the record from that id - to a different id.

*Of course if there is an easier way than a script, let me know!*

Need to change all the entries that have ID:2 - to ID:4

Thanks EE community!

Answer (score 2):

1. Perform DB backup incase this goes wrong.
2. Execute the follow statement

   `UPDATE exp_category_posts SET cat_id = 4 WHERE cat_id = 2`

Comment: That seems to work for entries where it is currently categorized as ONLY category 2.  What about entries that might be 2, 3, and 4 - and now I do not want category 2 (so only 3 and 4 in that case)?